# How can I get extended attributes with the Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I synchronized with Azure using AD Connect,
Extension attribute extension_ {ID} _ {attribute_name} is

This is available, but
https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/users

I can not do this.
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users

For MS reference, from now on, `graph.microsoft.com` is recommended for this use.
I would like to use Graph API.
By the way, I tried $ select = extension_ {ID} _ {attribute_name}, but
I can not get it.

Because it does not correspond in the first place

Comment: Can you please frame your question properly, highlighting the key points, so that others can easliy get idea of what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

I am glad to inform you that the problem is now solved.

It was a problem of permission.
Add `Directory.ReadWrite.All`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/xxxxxx@sample.com?$select=id,extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(id,extension_xxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName)/$entity",
    "id": "xxxxxxxx",
    "extension_xxxxxxxxx_msDS_PhoneticLastName": "furi_hoge"
}
```